# How to send encrypted email using PHP to a iOS device

Tags: php, ios, email, encryption

I am trying to send encrypted and signed emails using PHP, when finally I got it working, it is not working on iOS, when I try to open the email on an iPhone for example, I get the following error:
"This message is encrypted. Install a profile containing your encryption identity to decrypt this message."
The certificate is properly installed and it works perfectly if I send an encrypted email using outlook or mail from a mac, the problem is if I try to send it using PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer, seems like iOS only likes the Cipher 3DES so we need to tell PHP to use it:

I was encrypting using this code:

```
$encrypt = @openssl_pkcs7_encrypt(
                        $signed,
                        $encrypted,
                        file_get_contents($this->encrypt_cert_file),
                        null,
                        0,
                        1
                    );
```

I changed to:

```
$encrypt = @openssl_pkcs7_encrypt(
                        $signed,
                        $encrypted,
                        file_get_contents($this->encrypt_cert_file),
                        null,
                        0,
                        OPENSSL_CIPHER_3DES
                    );
```

It works now!
I hope this is helpful to somebody.